# WMQ (IBM MQ) - Create Queue with MQMDReadEnabled/mdReadEnabled flag true

Tags: header, jms, ibm-mq

I do have Java code client listener to listen to a MQ - Queue. Before we receive message, we enable Header Read Enable flag to get the header values.

Code is like this...

```
dest.setBooleanProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_MQMD_READ_ENABLED, true);
MQQueueManager qMgr = new MQQueueManager(qManager);
MQQueue queue = qMgr.accessQueue(qName);

// Can this be enabled in IBM MQ Creation level ????????????????????????
queue.setBooleanProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_MQMD_READ_ENABLED, true);

MQMessage rcvMessage = new MQMessage();
queue.get(rcvMessage, gmo);
System.out.println("Sample Header Value : " + rcvMessage.applicationIdData);
// Code to read Message Content...
```

Can **WMQConstants.WMQ_MQMD_READ_ENABLED** be enabled in IBM MQ Creation level ?????

Comment: You can look up the answer to your explicit question - first hit in google is https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q032330_.htm Therefore I assume you have tried it, and it didn't do what you expected. Perhaps you can say what happened when you used this code and how that differed from what you expected to happen?

Comment: P.S. If "IBM MQ Creation Level" meant you wanted to move that line of code somewhere else, please explain what you mean. I don't know what "IBM MQ Creation level" means.

Comment: Also, why are you trying to use a property that is meant for "MQ classes for JMS" with "MQ classes for Java"?  When you are using "MQ classes for Java", that property value is pointless, as shown by your println statement.  Please take some training before writing any more MQ code.

Comment: Thanks for replies. Wrapper class framework convert those values into JMS. But, we couldn't be able to access Message Object in framework than writing own Java client code. I hope, it does make sense. Thanks anyway...